# How to get data from object inside array of FireStore db using react

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

**how can i get this 'tags' data from firestore ?
i just want to get the spesific 'tags' from the 'blogs' object and push the tags to the array, in here i just have all of this tags data**

```
const [blogs, setBlogs] = useState([]);
  const [tags, setTags] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getBlogsData = async () => {
      const blogRef = collection(db, 'blogs');
      const blogs = await getDocs(blogRef);
      
      setBlogs(blogs.docs.map((doc) => ({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data })))
      
      blogs.docs.map((doc) => tags.push(...doc.get("tags")));
      let newTags = [...new Set(tags)];
      setTags(newTags);
    };
    getBlogsData();
  }, []);
```

This is my data from firestore database

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0: 
author: "jhon doe"
category: "Sports"
description: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text ..."
id: "123"
imgUrl: "https:........"
tags: Array(2)
0: {id: 'sport', text: 'sport'}
1: {text: 'liverpool', id: 'liverpool'}
length: 2
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
timestamp: nt {seconds: 1665798716, nanoseconds: 567000000}
title: 
"Sport Match Liverpool"
trending: "yes"
userId: "1234"
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

and this is what i get from the 'tags' how can i get just spesific tags from the object inside array ?

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {text: 'sport', id: 'sport'}
1: {text: 'liverpool', id: 'liverpool'}
2: {id: 'fashion', text: 'fashion'}
length: 3
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

thank you...

Comment: wdym by `tags` here ... ?

Comment: tags is nested object from my firestore db, and i just want to get the spesific tags data not get all of the tags data

Comment: oh my bad, you can `filter` it maybe or yeah I'm not sure if firebase has a filter itself ...

Comment: it's unclear what you're trying to do... are you trying to filter your blog docs by tags?

Comment: i just want to access nested array of object which is the text of  the tags object